# Loading lots of points on leaflet through time slider.

Tags: leaflet, point, clustering, timeslider

I'm trying to add more than 13 thousand point using [Time Slider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider), but as you can imagine the loading process of all these points puts a heavy burden on the map. Even the slider start to get sluggish. Is there any way to increase the application's performance? I played  bit with the [Marker Cluster plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) and it manage to handle all the points very well, but this was without the time slider. I tried to combine both but could not do it. Is it possible to combine both plugins? Or is there a better combination involving other plugins?

best,

Comment: Did you have any luck combining Marker cluster and leaflet slider?

Comment: No I did not. I decided to take a different approach by limiting how many points the time slider could add in total.

Answer (score 1):

[Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport)
Sub-plugin for Leaflet.markercluster plugin (MCG in short); brings compatibility with L.Control.Layers and other Leaflet plugins. I.e. everything that uses direct calls to map.addLayer and map.removeLayer.

Leaflet.markercluster plugin provides beautiful animated Marker Clustering functionality.

Leaflet is the leading open-source JavaScript library for mobile-friendly interactive maps.